# Sending mail using Indy and smtp

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe5

Im trying to send mail using this code:

```
With IdMessage1 Do Begin
  Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
  From.Address              := 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
  From.Name                 := edit_from.Text;
  CCList.EMailAddresses     := '';
  BccList.EMailAddresses    := '';
  Priority                  := mpNormal;
  Subject                   := edit_subject.Text;
  Body.Add(memo_body.Lines.Text);
End;

With IdSMTP1 Do Begin
  Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  Username  := 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
  Password  := '*****';
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  Port      := 465;
  UseTLS    := utUseImplicitTLS;

  Try
    Connect;
  Except
  End;

  If Not Connected Then Begin
    Showmessage('Error');
    Exit;
  End;

  Try
    Send(IdMessage1);
  Finally
    Disconnect;
  End;
End;
```

It works fine on my computer but when i test it on other machines the 'ERROR' (Error in `If` block before last `Try` block) will be raised...
Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you install the OpenSSL libraries on the other machines?

Comment: What "ERROR" is raised?

Comment: The error is probably telling you that the DLL's are missing. And you should never ask a question about an error in your code without telling us the error message / code.

Comment: i thought its clear what 'Error', but obviously it not, sorry for that...
before last Try block, there is a IF.. 

    If Not Connected Then Begin
      Showmessage('Error');
      Exit;
    End;

this 'Error' message is shown...

Comment: @SirRufo, no i did not install library... how should i do that?

Comment: Did you have a look at http://openssl.org ? There are some useful informations (fi. FAQ section) to get you started

Comment: There are OpenSSL DLLs available on Indy's Fulgan mirror: http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the proper way to do error handling with Indy.  It should be more like this instead:

```
With IdSMTP1 Do Begin
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Self);
  UseTLS    := utUseImplicitTLS;
  Host      := 'smtp.gmail.com';
  Username  := 'XXXXX@gmail.com';
  Password  := '*****';
  Port      := 465;

  Try
    Connect;
    Try
      Send(IdMessage1);
    Finally
      Disconnect;
    End;
  Except
    Showmessage('Error');
    Exit;
  End;
End;
```

`Send()` and `Disconnect()` can fail just as easily as `Connect()` can.  If you want `Connect()` to be in its own `try/except` block, then at least don't use `Connected` to validate whether `Connect()` succeeded:

```
Try
  Connect;
Except
  Showmessage('Error connecting');
  Exit;
End;

Try
  Try
    Send(IdMessage1);
  Finally
    Disconnect;
  End;
Except
  Showmessage('Error sending');
  Exit;
End;
```

That being said, the exception tells you what actually failed, so do not ignore it.  Had you displayed its content, you would have had a better idea of what was failing, eg:

```
Except
  on E: Exception do
  Begin
    ShowMessage(Format('Error!'#10'[%s] %s', [E.ClassName, e.Message]));
    Exit;
  End;
End;
```

The most likely culprit is that you did not deploy the OpenSSL DLLs with your app.  You can download them from [OpenSSL's website](http://www.openssl.org), or from [Indy's Fulgan mirror](http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL).

Comment: I used the exception and what i received was "Socket Error #11001 - Host not Found"

Comment: Then your machine's DNS subsystem is having trouble resolving smtp.gmail.com to an IP address.  That is outside of Indy.  Indy itself works fine with GMail when it is able to connect.